# sudo: effective uid is not 0 when running under tomcat service

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

I have a small java web app (grails), deployed under tomcat 8, from which I would like to execute a script on the local server using sudo. On a regular debian/ubuntu server all I have to do is use visudo to allow the tomcat user to execute sudo without a password on that particular script, and everything works as expected. When I tried installing the same war file on the raspberry pi (model 3b+, raspbian 10 - buster), booting from an SD card, the execution of the script always fails with the error "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges'.

In an effort to track down this issue I have written another small executable jar that performs the same function (i.e. attempts to launch the script using sudo). This test program works as expected when logged in interactively (bash) as both the 'pi' and 'tomcat8' users (I had to set a shell for the tomcat8 user to order to get an interactive login). I then used strace to try and diagnose the issue. All I could glean from that is that getuid() is returning 111 (tomcat8) when trying to launch sudo when running under the tomcat8 service, but will return 0 when running in bash.

I have also written a small c program that simply calls getuid() and prints the result. If I run it under the tomcat8 user interactively (i.e. sudo su tomcat8), it prints '111' when I run it without sudo, and '0' when I run it with sudo. When I try and launch this program from the web-app (using process builder) I get '111' when the command is run without sudo, but I get the 'effective uid is not 0 ...' error when the command is prefixed with sudo.

I have checked mount, and there are a number of mounts with the 'nosuid' attribute, but not the root '/' directory where /usr/bin is located, and /usr/bin/sudo looks to have the correct permissions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/dev $ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 147560 Jan 13  2019 /usr/bin/sudo
```

In desperation I have tried a couple of other things to just see what effect they might have:
* Added the tomcat8 user to adm, sudo and other groups
* Attempted to remount the other mounts without the nosuid attribute, although I couldn't remount about 6 or so because the mounts where in use.

Neither of these appeared to have any effect.

So it seems to me that the tomcat8 user can use sudo when in bash, but not when running as a daemon. Can anyone give me some ideas as to what is going on here? Is there anyway to diagnose or trace how an effective uid is determined by the os?

Other things that may be significant:
I installed both openjdk-8-jdk and tomcat8 via apt, and even though raspbian uses systemd, tomcat8 is launched via an init.d script. Not sure if this is causing uid issues.

If it is the SD card having some mounts with the nosuid attribute causing the problem, why doesn't it fail when running interactively?

Comment: It would be useful to know in what way I could improve this post to avoid the down votes.

Comment: The question is well asked, and you show what steps you took to figure out the problem. All of these steps lead in the completely wrong direction (which you didn't knew at the time of asking) and the reader gets a lot of information, none of which add to the problem. This makes it difficult for a reader to assess whether you are describing the same problem that they are having, therefore maybe the down votes. I would suggest (now, in retrospect) that you shorten the question to the first paragraph, because the rest of the question is no longer of any help.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out it was an issue with the way the daemon is started, probably due to changes in the way Debian 10 starts daemon processes. I removed the tomcat init.d script, and replaced it with a systemd unit file, and included the following properties:

```
[Service]
...
NoNewPrivileges=false
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID
SecureBits=keep-caps
```

This allows the daemon to actually call setUid(0) successfully.

Comment: It looks like `NoNewPrivileges=false` solves the problem (at least for me, on Ubuntu 20 LTS, it did). It is part of a sandboxing model of systemd, which is being introduced in the various Linux distributions at some point, and which restricts Tomcat additionally. `NoNewPrivileges=false` allows child processes to be executed under a different user if they have the `setuid` bit set on the file system. Apparently, the program `sudo` is executed under root by this means, and if this is not allowed, sudo is started under the Tomcat user and then cannot give the script any more permissions.